# Need to build Java application jar that includes script and dependencies using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have written a Java application and am using Maven to manage building. (This is *not* a Spring Boot application.) I need to be able to do the following:

- Include a script that will be the means for a user to execute the application.
- Produce a zip file containing the script, application and its dependencies. I don't care whether everything is built into a single jar file, or whether the dependencies are all separate and contained in a "lib" directory that's also part of the distribution. Whatever makes the most sense.
- Build an executable jar file. I am assuming this is the easiest way to run the application, but I could modify the script to run it the "non executable jar" way if needed.

I have been experimenting with the basic Maven jar and dependency plugins, as well as with the Maven assembly plugin. I can't figure out how to achieve all of the bullet points mentioned above.

I have been using Maven for quite some time, but it's been some years since I've needed to put together an application this way.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this are greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I've been focusing mainly on the assembly plugin, which I have used successfully in the past (although I don't think for this specific use case).

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>[hidden]</groupId>
    <artifactId>cold-storage-nospring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>archive</artifactId>

  <properties>
    <maven-assembly-plugin.version>3.4.2</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <finalName>archive-gitlab-project</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <!-- Assembly plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>assemble</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

assembly.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.1 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.1.xsd">
  <id>make-assembly</id>

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <files>
    <file>
      <source>target/archive-gitlab-project.jar</source>
      <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
    </file>

    <file>
      <source>src/main/resources/archive-project.sh</source>
      <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>
</assembly>
```

Comment: The [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) can be used to create a "fat JAR" = a JAR file that contains all the dependencies of an application (so that you need only one JAR file).

Comment: Will this allow me to achieve the objectives mentioned?

Comment: It allows you to build a single JAR file that contains everything the application needs. It can also make it an [executable JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) for you. Writing the script is something you need to do youself (but that script will be only one or two lines) and putting everything in a zip file is also you need to do yourself (but that's a simple terminal command). (I didn't downvote).

Comment: Yes, I have already written the script. Just need to include it in the zip with the app and dependencies.
Wait, the shade plugin does not have the ability to package all of this in a zip file? It'd useful if it did as part of the build process.

Comment: The assembly plugin can create a zip. You could add your script in the resources of your project and copy those with the maven resources plugin to the output so it can be included in the assembly.

Comment: Yes, I'm experimenting with that now. I can get it build a zip file with the script and jar inside, but the jar does not include any dependencies. I'm also not sure if it's an executable jar. I can't figure out how to get it to build the jar with dependencies **and** pull in the script. If I try to use the "jar-with-dependencies" descriptor ref, it produces that, but I can't get that into the zip file.